# Using dnsmasq with KVM

Tags: centos, arch-linux, kvm-switch, dhcp-server

I just installed KVM on a CentOS 7 x64 minimal installation version at home. And I got a problem when the guest is trying to get an IP from the internal DHCP server from KVM (dnsmasq).

I already have my internet box with DHCP on and I know it's bad when 2 DHCP servers are running on the same LAN.

When I do a tcpdump on the KVM host and the guest, I see that this is my internet box dhcp which is responding to the guest DHCP request and not the dnsmasq (but the guest still not getting an IP, even when my internet box dhcp is pushing one to the guest). Is there a way to isolate the guest to only get an IP from the dnsmasq dhcp server ?

Here is my configuration for now:

```
em1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::222:19ff:fe68:25de  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:22:19:68:25:de  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 22167  bytes 1671094 (1.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 16  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35434  bytes 7868453 (7.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 9  bytes 4172 (4.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9  bytes 4172 (4.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.250  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether 00:22:19:68:25:de  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 22056  bytes 1266640 (1.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 99  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34413  bytes 7636993 (7.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And the result from the default network with virsh:

```
[root@centosKVM ~]# virsh net-info default
Name            default
UUID            ff41aa4b-b4b0-4047-b1af-545e3b8f19cd
Active:         yes
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      yes
Bridge:         virbr0

[root@centosKVM ~]# virsh net-dumpxml default
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>ff41aa4b-b4b0-4047-b1af-545e3b8f19cd</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0' />
  <mac address='00:22:19:68:25:de'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.100' end='192.168.122.254' />
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

I created the guest with the following command:

```
virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n archlinux --cpu host -r 512 --vcpus=1 --disk path=/mnt/raid5/img/archlinux.raw,bus=virtio --cdrom /mnt/usb/archlinux-2015.02.01-dual.iso --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 --noautoconsole --os-type linux --accelerate --network model=virtio,bridge=virbr0 --hvm
```

I typed the following commands to open iptables and make sure he's not blocking anything:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

If you need more informations or/and details, just ask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
--network model=virtio,network=default
```

instead of

```
--network model=virtio,bridge=virbr0
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: this is not a whole answer, because a problem could be in another place. but it is a good place to start. it is better than no answers at all.